# How to display a custom property of `IdentityUser` class in all `Views`?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

How to display a custom property of `IdentityUser` class in all `Views`?

I want to display a `PublicName` and the `Email` of the current logged-in user in the top navigation bar (in the default bootstrap template, made by `VisualStudio` only the `Email` of the current logged-in user is displayed) which is in the `Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom WebViewPage Base

```
 public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
 {
  public IdentityUser User { 
      get { // return your IdentityUser object here }
  }
}
```

And configure it as the new base for razor views in the Views/web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="YourApp.CustomWebViewPage"></pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

You can now access the User property in any view and print the value.

```
@this.User.Email
```

Comment: That won't run. Cast `Thread.CurrentUser as IdentityUser` will throw exception, as these are not related classes.

Comment: Yes just noticed what type he was referring to, it's not an user principal but from asp.net identity EF class, I'll update answer to abstract this fact .

Comment: Which extension must the `CustomWebViewPage` have? `.cs`?

Comment: take a look at these articles: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/ , http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-change-base-type-of-razor-view-engine-pages/

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... Because the definitions of methods like `BeginForm()` and `ActionLink()` of the `Html` class are missing now. I double checked my namespaces and paths in web.config but all seems to be fine. :/

Comment: derive from the generic WebViewPage<TModel>, answer updated, and add the config to Views/Web.config

Comment: As soon as i add this: `<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="WebApp.Razor.CustomWebViewPage">
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>` into my `Web.config` file, the methods of class `Html` get lost.

Comment: The namespace in my `WebApp/Razor/CustomWebViewPage.cs` file is: `namespace WebApp.Razor` and in it, i have just this right now: `public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
    {
       
    }` i also tried `public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>` and `public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage`. None worked. :(

Comment: It works perfect. I edited the wrong `Web.config`. Edited `WebApp/WebApp.config`, instead of `WebApp/Views/WebApp.config`. It had to be something this stupid. (facepalm) xD And `public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>` was the only one working.